# jOOQ select with map type values

Tags: java, sql, jooq

There is a table that has map type column, and the map column type would be like below

```
Map<String, CustomClass.class>
```

and CustomClass is like below

```
Class CustomClass {
   String name;
   String attr;
}
```

I would like to select record that match 'keyword' contain in map column's values (no matter what key is). I need something like below. Is there any way that I can use?

```
JooqQuery jooqQuery = (SelectJoinStep<?> step) -> {
  
    step.where(MANAGERS.NAME_DESC_I18N_MAP.contains(
          Map<"ANY KEY", keyword in CustomClass.name> // need help here
      ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIKE` as a [quantified comparison predicate](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/quantified-comparison-predicate/) in jOOQ. If it's not supported natively by your RDBMS, jOOQ will emulate it for you. Try this:

```java
MANAGERS.NAME_DESC_I18N_MAP.like(any(
    map.values().stream().map(cc -> "%" + cc.name + "%").toArray(String[]::new)
))
```

You can't use `contains()` in this way yet, but I guess that's OK.

See also this blog post about using [`LIKE` as a quantified comparison predicate](https://blog.jooq.org/quantified-like-any-predicates-in-jooq-3-12/).